# How do I fix my error?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT 
      hospital_general_information.provider_id,
      hosptial_name hospital_associated_infection,
      provider_id,     
      readmission_complications_deaths.provider_id
FROM
      hosptial_general_information
JOIN  hospital_associated_infection 
      ON hospital_general_information.provider_id = hosptial_associated_infection.provider_id
JOIN  hospital_associated_infection 
      ON hospital_associated_infection.provider_id = readmission_complications_deaths.provider_id
```

Comment: I am getting an error code 1066 and cannot figure out why. Thank you!

Comment: I'd suspect that `hosptial_name` is in multiple tables and need to be quantified with the table you mean. The error message normally points to where in the query the error is. Please try [formatting sql](http://sqlformat.org/) to be more readable and showing the complete error message. Table structure `SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}` helps too.

Comment: I suggest you edit the question and provide code that doesn't have typos (hospital/hosptial). Some formatting would be nice, too.

Answer (score 2):

First of all.. You need to make your query `Readable`.. `Readable` are feature to help you find `Error` like `Typo` or `Missing`.

```
select 
   hospital_general_information.provider_id, 
   hosptial_name hospital_associated_infection,
   provider_id, 
   readmission_complications_deaths.provider_id 
from 
   hosptial_general_information 
   join hospital_associated_infection 
     on hospital_general_information.provider_id=hosptial_associated_infection.provider_id 
   join hospital_associated_infection 
     on hospital_associated_infection.provider_id=readmission_complications_deaths.provider_id
```

This is your query first.. Some error i found

```
hosptial_name hospital_associated_infection
```

You have space in there and Typo when should be `hospital` become `hosptial` and You are wrong calling the column.. Syntax are `table.column`

```
provider_id,
```

You call `provider_id` and i see your join use this `column` so it will produce error too, `Ambiguous Error` Because `provider_id` more than 1 and you should identify who `provider_id` this supposed to be belong.

```
hospital_associated_infection.provider_id=readmission_complications_deaths.provider_id
```

And this is your 2nd join condition.. You just assign 2 tables `hospital_associated_infection` and `hospital_general_information` so who `readmission_complications_deaths`? You must assign this table.

And you have so many `Typo` in `Hospital`..

So if this is your query should be..

```
select 
   hospital_general_information.provider_id, 
   hospital_associated_infection.hospital_name,
   hospital_associated_infection.provider_id, 
   readmission_complications_deaths.provider_id 
from 
   hospital_general_information 
   join hospital_associated_infection 
     on hospital_general_information.provider_id=hospital_associated_infection.provider_id 
   join readmission_complications_deaths
     on hospital_associated_infection.provider_id=readmission_complications_deaths.provider_id
```

And i suggest you use `aliasing` for your table.. Because your table name so long. And i recommend use letter like `hgi` stands for `hospital_general_information`

Answer (score 1):

Is 1066 "names too verbose"?

Sorry.  Seriously, when joining to the same table twice, give each copy an alias:

```
select  gi.provider_id,
        hosptial_name AS hospital_associated_infection,
        provider_id,
        rcd.provider_id
    from  hosptial_general_information AS gi
    join  readmission_complications_deaths AS rcd
       ON ???
    join  hospital_associated_infection AS ai_1
       ON ai_1.provider_id = gi.provider_id
    join  hospital_associated_infection AS ai_2 
       ON ai_2.provider_id = rcd.provider_id
```

Or was it a typo?  `readmission_complications_deaths` was needed instead of a second reference to `hospital_associated_infection`

Oh, is there a missing comma?